# How to route on a Shapefile?

Tags: pgrouting, routing

We use shp.file in our VB6 to run tracking system. Now we want to convert it into the navigation system, which requires doing the route analysis on shp.file. The route is drawn in shp.file

Usually, we see the route analysis is on the grid when programmed it using Visual Studio 6. How to make it to run on shp.file?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? You have a shape file that you'd like perform routing analysis on using pgrouting? What are you trying to achieve? and what have you done so far to get there?

Comment: You can't actually run pgRouting (which uses PostgreSQl/PostGIS) on a shapefile without importing it into the PostGIS database.  Are you actually just looking for any routing solution that works on a shapefile?

Answer (score 2):

You can use our software "RW Net 4" for doing route calculations on SHP files. It includes a COM version which is compatible with VB6. Please see www.routeware.dk for further information.